# Referência bibliográfica no LaTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex

Estou tentando criar um arquivo `.bib`, mas meu arquivo `.tex` só exibe o primeiro. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
@book{Boaventura,
  title={Grafos: Teorias, modelos, algoritmos},
  author={Boaventura Netto, P. O.},
  isbn={9788521203919},
  url={http://www.blucher.com.br/produto/03919/grafos:-teoria-modelos-algoritmos-4-edicao-revista-e-ampliada},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Blucher}
}

@book{Ziviani,
  title={Projetos de Algoritmos com implementações em Pascal e C},
  author={Ziviani, N.},
  isbn={9788522110506},
  url={http://www2.dcc.ufmg.br/livros/algoritmos/index.php},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Cengage Learning}
}
```

Comment: As referências do `.bib` só são incluídas se forem utilizadas no corpo do seu trabalho. É possível que você não tenha referenciado ou tenha referenciado de forma errada o segundo livro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimentei o teu bibtex e funcionou bem.

```
\documentclass[portuges,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\cite{Ziviani}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}          % ou plain ou ...
\bibliography{patricia}            % patricia.bib
\end{document}
```

pelo que deduzo que te faltaria colocar o `\cite{...}`. Se não for esse o caso, junta um micro exemplo com o teu texto.

Por vezes, para a fase de debug do BiBTeX, colocar `\nocite{*}` pode ser util (despeja toda a bibliografia sem haver citações)

Comment: Correto o bibtex só adiciona referências bibliográficas que foram utilizadas no texto.

Comment: Valeu JJoao e Flávio! O problema era exatamente esse: as referências não usadas não eram impressas. Usei o \nocite{*} e o problema foi solucionado.